# (Python) Add UI Button to the Grease Pencil DOPESHEET Header using Python

Tags: python, interface

I would like to add few buttons to the DOPESHEET header when it is set to Grease Pencil Mode.
At the moment I can add buttons before or after using prepend and append methods.
The problem I struggle with has two parts:

- When I add the buttons they are added to all DOPESHEETS regardles of what mode they are on
- I have no clue how to put the buttons in between existing buttons. Not sure if there is an easy way to do it with python.

Here a simple code:

```
import bpy

def TEST_HT_view3d(self, context):

    self.layout.operator(
        operator='mesh.primitive_cube_add',
        icon='MESH_CUBE',
        text=''
    )
    
bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.append(TEST_HT_view3d)
```

And here is a little image showing the problem and what I am trying to accomplish.
The red squares show where I would love to locate few buttons. As you can see I would them to only appear on GreasePencil DOPESHEET.
The yellow circles show how I can add buttons with append and prepend methods but they show up on all DOPESHEETS and even TIMELINE.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions and help!

=== UPDATE ===

So it turns out part of my question was actually pretty trivial. In order to make sure the buttons are added only to the GreasePencil mode of DOPESHEET we can alter the above code like this:

```
import bpy

def TEST_HT_view3d(self, context):

    st = context.space_data
    if st.mode == 'GPENCIL':

        self.layout.operator(
            operator='mesh.primitive_cube_add',
            icon='MESH_CUBE',
            text=''
        )
    
bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.append(TEST_HT_view3d)
```

Still don't know how to put the button in between the default buttons though (the red rectangles in the image)

Mac

Comment: I was also wondering how to avoid. When registering workspacetools it can look like this, with a keyword after bpy.utils.register_tool(YourTool, after={"builtin.rip_edge"}, separator=True, group=True), but bpy.types.NODE_HT_header.append() says there is no keyword after...

Comment: For me I just used bpy.types.NODE_MT_editor_menus.append instead of bpy.types.NODE_HT_header.append() and my icons ended up just to the right of menus like Add and Node in the Node Editor...